# Creating JSON object stops code from continuing with pymongo

Tags: json, mongodb, pymongo

I'm currently trying to create a JSON object to insert into a mongoDB database. However, when I create my JSON object, it appears to reach the end of the creation and then won't continue onto the insert statement in order to place the JSON object in the database. Here is an example of my code. For security reasons, I've changed some of the sensitive code to 99999, but I've verified that the authorisation section of the code works.

'''

```
    client = MongoClient('9999999', 999999) # LAN

    db = client.999999

    site = client.99999   
    db.authenticate('9999999', '999999')  # user authentication

    collection = site.9999999


    test = {
        'Timestamp': timestamp(),
        'Device Type': device,
        'Instrument Serial': instrumentserial,
        'Calibration Date': cal,
        'Survey Date': dateofsurvey,
        'Survey Time': timeofsurvey,
        'Site Name': nameofsite,
        'Survey Location': survloc,
        'Frequency Survey Reference': survref,
        'Voltage': v,
        'Insulation': ins,
        'Tuner Select': tunerselect,
        'Start Frequency': frequency,
        'Reference Level': referencelevel,
        'RBW': rbw,
        'Instrument Mode': instrumentmode,
        'Detector Mode': detectormode,
        'Sweep Rate': sweeprate,
        'Trigger Mode': triggermode,
        'Trigger Level': triggerlevel,
        }

    collection.insert_one(test)
```

'''

All the variables have been parsed from an xml file. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as the code appears to just stop.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: `collection.insert_one(test)` is correct query? or `collection.insertOne(test)`? is correct

Comment: I don't get any errors. And I changed that query based on your input, but I'm still not placing anything in the database.

Comment: Python/PyMongo needs pretty much everything in quotes. Try quoting all your values like - `'Timestamp': 'timestamp()',`.

Comment: This fixed it, and it now writes to the database, but just as if the variable name is now the string in the database related to each title, not the value.